# Conditionally add class to image using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am a novice at javascript and I would really appreciate help with this.

I want to give classes to images in specific div based on the dimensions.

For images that are portrait, I want to give it a class portrait, for images that are ladscape class landscape and images that are square square. I am doing this by dividing width by height and if the value equals 1 I give this image a class of square, if bigger than 1 landscape, if samller than 1 portrait.

I am doing this to give images in a div with different aspect ratio different css style.

I want to do this to not all images but images in specific divs. In my example in div class "detailsection" and also div class "imagesection"

I can't get the code to work right. I am having difficulty specifying specific div and image.

Appreciate all the help.

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $('.imagesection > img').each(function() {
    if ($(this).width() / $(this).height() > 1) {
      $(this).addClass('landscape');
    } else if ($(this).width() / $(this).height() >= 1) {
      $(this).addClass('square');
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('portrait');
    }
  });
});

$(window).on('load', function() {
  $('.detailsection > img').each(function() {
    if ($(this).width() / $(this).height() > 1) {
      $(this).addClass('landscape');
    } else if ($(this).width() / $(this).height() >= 1) {
      $(this).addClass('square');
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('portrait');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.imagesection {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.imagesection img {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.imagesection img.landscape {
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 70%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 5% 15%;
}

.imagesection img.portrait {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: left;
}

.detailsection {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.detailsection img {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.detailsection img.landscape {
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 70%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 5% 15%;
}

.detailsection img.portrait {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="detailsection">
  <!--Detail Title Image-->
  <div class="titlepg">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x1000" alt="" class="titlepg">
  </div>
  <!--Detail Title Image-->

  <!--Detail Spec Image-->
  <div class="specpg">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x1000" alt="" class="specpg">
  </div>
  <!--Detail Spec Image-->

  <!--Detail Option Image-->
  <div class="optionpg">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x1000" alt="" class="optionpg">
  </div>
  <!--Detail Option Image-->

  <!--Detail Detail Image pg-->
  <div class="detailimagepg">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x500" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x1000" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x1000" />
  </div>
  <!--Detail Detail Image pg-->

</div>

<div class="imagesection">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x500" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x1000" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x1000" />
</div>
```

Comment: first of your missing an `}` after each of your `else if ` statements

Comment: Another issue is that `.detailsection > img` will not select any of the images inside your `detailsection` class as they're not direct descendants.

Comment: This is how I'd do it: https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/423kj6ur/1/. Selector is `$('img', '.imagesection, .detailsection')` and class assignment is done inside `addClass()`, using ternary checks, since they're pretty straight forward. And, of course, you don't need two blocks of code for each `<div>`. See [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Answer (score 2):

Remove the > from your selector.

```
.imagesection > img
```

becomes

```
.imagesection img
```

Answer (score 2):

I whould suggest that you should create a function and call it foreach of the desired image:

```
function applyImageClass(image) {
   var h = (image) ? image.height() : 0;
   if (h > 0) {
       var ratio = image.width() / h;
       if (ratio === 1) {
           image.addClass('square');
       } else if (ratio > 1) {
           image.addClass('landscape');
       } else if (ratio < 1) {
           image.addClass('portrait');
       }
   }      
}

$(window).on('load', function() {
    // Find all images contained in any element that has any of the tow classes
    $('.imagesection, .detailsection').find('img').each(function() {
        // Call the function for each one of the matched elements
        applyImageClass($(this));
    });
});
```

Comment: `$('.imagesection, .detailsection').find('img')` => `$('img','.imagesection,.detailsection')`

Answer (score -1):

close else if statement with } properly in your code.

and then just Remove the > from your selector.

```
'.detailsection > img'
```

to be changed to

```
'.detailsection img'
```

and to have clear code I recommend @kapantzak answer.